# tmux run fish shell functions returns error 127

Tags: tmux, fish

In my `.tmux.conf` I have those lines:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/fish

bind -n M-I run "fish_prompt"
```

But pressing `M-I` I get error 127 as response. Ordinary bash functions like `echo 123` works fine, only fish functions are not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default-shell` sets the shell to use in a new pane; it doesn't affect the shell used by the `run-shell` command, which remains `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Shell I calling tmux command also fish, so how do I change shell used by `run-shell` then?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

As explained above, `run-shell` always uses `/bin/sh` (as defined by `_PATH_BSHELL` in tmux's source).

To run a fish shell, you can use `run "fish -c fish_prompt"`, but that mucks up the escape characters and produces the output in a not-terribly-helpful way.

What output do you want to see - are you using `fish_prompt` or some other function?